# The contents of (something) are/were/name?/etc

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, word-usage

I am trying to find a more suitable word for the sentence:

> She presented to him the contents of her other hand: which **(enter word here)** a small corked bottle that contained a small parchment of paper.

I thought about: was, numbered, named, included. But none of these seem specific enough. "Was" is just meh, and the other words just don't seem to be correctly used in this sentence.

So, any suggestions?

Also, should I write "the contents" or "the content", in this sentence.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: One thing worth noting: if you use a colon, the following bit should not be a relative clause, so "which [verb]" should be omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using words such as: contained, comprised of, included ....
As for content vs. contents, I would definitely use contents. Content as a singular noun is uncountable, while contents expresses the “contents of a bag”, “contents of a bottle”, “contents of the stomach”, etc. While what she is holding is one item, singularly, it in total is still the contents of her hand.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use: **which consisted of**.... I suggest you use the **content**, since there is only one object in question.